# What is the maximum string length which can be passed as a variable in a parameterized job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, parameters

What is the maximum string length which can be passed as a variable in a parameterized  job in Jenkins in a single variable.

Answer (score 9):

I've asked my self this same question, and I did search in jenkins docs for the answer without success, so, I tried by myself to pass huge params. I've tested to pass **params with more than ten thousands characteres** with success, and this is a safe number for me. I still don't knowing the max lenth, but I know that string param has length enough for my needs. I hope it helps.